# Delete certain line while using iperf

Tags: grep, iperf

I run iperf command like this :

```
 iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 2 -f m -w 1K | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'
```

I want to display throughput only such as 0.32 but because I use 1K here, there is a warning and the display becomes

```
 WARNING: TCP window size set to 1024 bytes. A small window size will give poor performance. See the Iperf documentation.
 0.32
```

How to delete this warning so I can get "0.32" only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the warning message to `/dev/null`, after that you get output only.

So your command would be,

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 2 -f m -w 1K 2> /dev/null | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'
```

Comment: what do you mean by sending to /dev/null here? how to send via bash script?

Comment: `command 2> /dev/null`, this will remove warning mesages and prints only the output.

Comment: I use like this : iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 2 -f m -w 1K 2> /dev/null | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'  and it works. Thank you

Comment: @user2290560 yep you have to use it on the `iperf` command because this command itself only produces the warning message.